# Fetch all songs from specific path

Tags: android, mediastore

I am trying to fetch all songs from a specific folder. Currently, I am fetching all songs and then on basis of path I am looping and getting songs in the specific path.Any better way to do this?

```
 for (int i = 0; i < totalSongList.size(); i++) {
        String path = totalSongList.get(i).getPathId();
        int index = path.lastIndexOf("/");
        String folderPath1 = path.substring(0, index);

        if (folderPath.equals(folderPath1))
            songList.add(totalSongList.get(i));

    }
```

I can't use below code also as it will fetch sub folder songs also.

```
musicResolver.query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null,MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA + " like ? ",
        new String[] {"%SPECIFIC_FOLDER_NAME%"},  null);
```

Comment: You can write java code to search for all songs present in specific folder instead of using mediastore.

Comment: Can you please give an example for the same?

Answer (score 0):

Here is java code without using mediaStore for retrieving all songs from the specific folder which may or maynot contain any subfolder.

```
public String File path = new File("your folder path here");

public void Search(File dir)
{
if(dir.isFile())
{
//get necessary songName over here
String songName = dir.getName();

//if you need path
String songPath = dir.getAbsolutePath();

//if your folder consists of other files other than audio you have to filer it 

if(songName.endsWith(".mp3") || songName.endsWith(".MP3")
{
//this is the required mp3 files
//do what you want to do with it
}

}else if(dir.isDirectory())
{
File[] list = dir.listFiles();

for(int i=0;i<list.length();i++)
{
search(list[i]);
}

}
else
{
//handle exceptions here
}     


}
```